# php Socket Socket_bind() unable to bind address [10013]

Tags: php, sockets, telnet

My situation:

- I have a program which send on a port (4448) a lot of data from some machines.
- I can retrieve that datas from a telnet connection.

telnet steps:

- launch as cmd as ADMIN
- write telnet and send
- write "open localhost 4448" and send
- write "GET xx,yy"
- after this i just read on screen info in live

xx and yy are numbers which identifies the machine

Now lets go on php side I have my index.php but when I execute socket bind it gives me back an error (reported under the code) and about the code, this come from: http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php and its the first example, i read and tried this solution also https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/418814/Socket-Programming-in-PHP which use 2 php files, in both cases i get the same error...

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Allow the script to hang around waiting for connections. */
set_time_limit(0);

/* Turn on implicit output flushing so we see what we're getting
 * as it comes in. */
ob_implicit_flush();

$address = 'localhost';
$port = 4448;

if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}

if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) {
    echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

do {
    if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) {
        echo "socket_accept() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
        break;
    }
    /* Send instructions. */
    $msg = "GET xx,yy";
    socket_write($msgsock, $msg, strlen($msg));

    do {
        if (false === ($buf = socket_read($msgsock, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ))) {
            echo "socket_read() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($msgsock)) . "\n";
            break 2;
        }
        if (!$buf = trim($buf)) {
            continue;
        }
        if ($buf == 'quit') {
            break;
        }
        if ($buf == 'shutdown') {
            socket_close($msgsock);
            break 2;
        }
        $talkback = "PHP: You said '$buf'.\n";
        socket_write($msgsock, $talkback, strlen($talkback));
        echo "$buf\n";
    } while (true);
    socket_close($msgsock);
} while (true);

socket_close($sock);
?>
```

and this is the error i get:

> Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [10013]: An attempt was
>   made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

I have already looked for administrator privileges and I think its all right.

Extra info: I am working with PHP 7, my web server is Apache in Xampp package.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible another program is already using that port. Try using a different port. If that works you can try finding the process using the port and terminating it. This tool from sysinternals may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview

If using a different port also fails, a possiblity is that you have a firewall that doesn't allow bind. Try disabling your firewall temporarily.

Comment: i have already tried with others port numbers 25 different port and all of them surely free... and i have disabled firewall too